# ASP.NET Bootstrap wrong display

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I was looking up this style on bootswatch: https://bootswatch.com/simplex/

And especially looked for styling forms, like here:

[image: Style as shown on bootswatch.com]

But when I add the code that you get when clicking on the little red icon in the top right of the form example on bootswatch to my website, it looks like this:

[image: Wrong Display]

So the text labels and input fields have a line break inbetween them, the a little darker shaded background box isnt shown and other things are misaligned, too. How does that come?

This is the entire code of my Page:

```
@model WebProto.ViewModels.NewChartConfigViewModel
@using MaschinenModell;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Neues Diagramm";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Legend</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Textarea</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea"></textarea>
                <span class="help-block">A longer block of help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend beyond one line.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Radios</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
                        Option one is this
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
                        Option two can be something else
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Selects</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="select">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <select multiple="" class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay im so flipping stupid. Its because I displayed the webpage I created in internet explorer. My fault! :D

Firefox, Opera and Chrome show it correctly.